# read system call freeze

Tags: linux, strace

I have a VPS which sometimes suddenly got stuck. Recently I found ssh session will get stuck when I run ps aux. After run `strace ps aux` I got below.

```
stat("/proc/1573", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/1573/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "1573 (sshd) D 506 1573 1573 0 -1"..., 2048) = 335
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/1573/status", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "Name:\tsshd\nUmask:\t0022\nState:\tD "..., 2048) = 1287
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/1573/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6,
```

Seems ps aux is freezed in the last read system call which looks like a sshd process. I run `cat /proc/1573/cmdline` can also reproduce this problem. It's my first time to investigate this kind of issue. Can anyone point me how to resolve this problem. Is it a hardware issue?

Comment: try calling `strace` with `-T`, it'll show the amount of time taken for a syscall.